# local docker image using python packages - ModuleNotFoundError

Tags: python, docker

So I have an image that contains a machine learning model api, but it needs some specific python packages. I tried to setup a virtualenv with all the packages needed in the dockerfile so when I build the image, the python env is built properly and then it can build and run my local image. When I run docker build : `docker build my-container/ -f dockerfile -t my-detector`, everything seems to work properly, but then when I run it using this command : `docker run -d --name my-container/ my-detector`, the container starts and then stops. So I took a look at the logs, and this is the error :

```
Downloading: "https://github.com/ultralytics/yolov5/zipball/master" to /root/.cache/torch/hub/master.zip

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/uvicorn", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/click/core.py", line 1130, in __call__
    return self.main(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/click/core.py", line 1055, in main
    rv = self.invoke(ctx)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/click/core.py", line 1404, in invoke
    return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/click/core.py", line 760, in invoke
    return __callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/uvicorn/main.py", line 408, in main
    run(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/uvicorn/main.py", line 576, in run
    server.run()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/uvicorn/server.py", line 60, in run
    return asyncio.run(self.serve(sockets=sockets))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/asyncio/runners.py", line 44, in run
    return loop.run_until_complete(main)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/asyncio/base_events.py", line 616, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/uvicorn/server.py", line 67, in serve
    config.load()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/uvicorn/config.py", line 479, in load
    self.loaded_app = import_from_string(self.app)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/uvicorn/importer.py", line 24, in import_from_string
    raise exc from None
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/uvicorn/importer.py", line 21, in import_from_string
    module = importlib.import_module(module_str)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 848, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/usr/src/app/./worker.py", line 9, in <module>
    model = torch.hub.load("ultralytics/yolov5", "custom", path="best.onnx")
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/torch/hub.py", line 540, in load
    model = _load_local(repo_or_dir, model, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/torch/hub.py", line 569, in _load_local
    model = entry(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/root/.cache/torch/hub/ultralytics_yolov5_master/hubconf.py", line 83, in custom
    return _create(path, autoshape=autoshape, verbose=_verbose, device=device)
  File "/root/.cache/torch/hub/ultralytics_yolov5_master/hubconf.py", line 33, in _create
    from models.common import AutoShape, DetectMultiBackend
  File "/root/.cache/torch/hub/ultralytics_yolov5_master/models/common.py", line 28, in <module>
    from utils.dataloaders import exif_transpose, letterbox
  File "/root/.cache/torch/hub/ultralytics_yolov5_master/utils/dataloaders.py", line 31, in <module>
    from utils.augmentations import (Albumentations, augment_hsv, classify_albumentations, classify_transforms, copy_paste,
  File "/root/.cache/torch/hub/ultralytics_yolov5_master/utils/augmentations.py", line 15, in <module>
    from utils.general import LOGGER, check_version, colorstr, resample_segments, segment2box, xywhn2xyxy
  File "/root/.cache/torch/hub/ultralytics_yolov5_master/utils/general.py", line 38, in <module>
    from ultralytics.yolo.utils.checks import check_requirements
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ultralytics'.
```

The issue here is that I have this package and all the sub dependencies listed in requirements.txt, and so after activating the venv, upgrading pip and installing the requirements it should have everything needed to build my-detector.

This is my dockerfile :

```
FROM python:3.8 as python

WORKDIR my-container

RUN python3 -m venv venv
ENV PYTHONPATH my-container/venv/bin
COPY requirements.txt requirements.txt
RUN . ./venv/bin/activate && pip install --upgrade pip && pip install -r requirements.txt


FROM my-detector:1.0.0

EXPOSE 80
```

Finally, here is the content of requirements.txt :

```
certifi==2023.5.7
charset-normalizer==3.1.0
contourpy==1.0.7
cycler==0.11.0
filelock==3.12.0
fonttools==4.39.4
idna==3.4
importlib-resources==5.12.0
Jinja2==3.1.2
kiwisolver==1.4.4
MarkupSafe==2.1.2
matplotlib==3.7.1
mpmath==1.3.0
networkx==3.1
numpy==1.24.3
opencv-python==4.7.0.72
packaging==23.1
pandas==2.0.1
Pillow==9.5.0
psutil==5.9.5
pyparsing==3.0.9
python-dateutil==2.8.2
pytz==2023.3
PyYAML==6.0
requests==2.30.0
scipy==1.10.1
seaborn==0.12.2
sentry-sdk==1.22.2
six==1.16.0
sympy==1.12
thop==0.1.1.post2209072238
torch==2.0.1
torchvision==0.15.2
tqdm==4.65.0
typing_extensions==4.5.0
tzdata==2023.3
ultralytics==8.0.100
urllib3==1.26.15
zipp==3.15.0
```

Comment: Yes it's included, before building anything I made a fresh venv, installed ultralytics so I could generate all the dependencies needed by this package with : ```pip freeze > requirements.txt```, and that's this file that I'm using for ```pip install -r requirements.txt```

Comment: Makes sense, and ought to work, I agree! Next question: did you create that env on the same OS as this docker image?

Comment: Well I don't think I need to worry about the OS since I'm basically just using python, and the main idea with python is that I can be run on almost any OS. Once the machine learning module image is running, it's just exposed on localhost so I can make a post request providing a file path and getting a JSON from the detection api. So I just need to make sure the python prerequisites work in order the build this custom image I think. But I might be wrong

Comment: Well, yeah, it should be portable, but by experience if you're crossing the Windows/Linux boundary, that assumption does not always hold. If you're using different flavours of Linux, though, that's usually not a problem.

Comment: I just tried to reproduce, and quickly noticed that you didn't share your `my-detector:1.0.0` image. My next question is, then, did you make sure that that image is using the python env you created in this image? It's not clear to me how that connection can happen with this Dockerfile, to be honest.

Comment: Did you forget to include a COPY directive to place the venv in the final image? See https://www.docker.com/blog/dockerfiles-now-support-multiple-build-contexts/

Comment: The docker image was create from a Linux env, and I created mine on macOS Big Sur. Well the idea is that I need to be able to build and run this image to have access to the detection api on localhost, but for this I need to build and setup the python env and packages needed by the detector image. The image uses a list of packages that are needed to run it, that's why I'm doing all of this.

Comment: But here you have two `FROM` directives, and that means you're building two images. When you're building multi-stage images using docker, you would normally copy some artefact from the first image into the second one, but you're not doing that here. Again, see https://www.docker.com/blog/dockerfiles-now-support-multiple-build-contexts/

Comment: I'm going to take a look at the copy directive thank you. Well it's supposed to stick around and keep running just like a database for example. It's listening to certain ports, and in this case one port that allows me to make a post request

Comment: Hello @arlaine, why the virtual environment (python venv) it is required along your dockerfile?, based in your services architectures & from mi POV it is not usefull

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you create a docker image using a multi-stage build, you need to copy the created artefact from the first image into the second image.

This should do the trick, for the second stage of your Dockerfile:

```
FROM my-detector:1.0.0

COPY --from=python /my-container/venv /my-container/venv

EXPOSE 80
```

Assumptions: your `my-detector` image already has the `CMD` instruction required to spin up your server, and it is already expecting to find the Python venv in that location.

If these assumptions are wrong, you might also need to add a line like this at the end:

```
CMD . /my-container/venv/bin/activate && <cmd to run your API server>
```

Comment: I tried adding the COPY and CMD line you suggested, and it doesn't fix the issue

Comment: @arlaine Would you be able to share your Dockerfile for `my-detector` as well? If this didn't work, I don't think we have enough information to answer your question yet. FrancoGil is right, it's odd to be using a venv, and I also think it's odd to do a two-stage build for your use case instead of installing python and your modules in the my-detector base image.